# Generate accurate 20mV Vref

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-reference

I want to generate 20mV Vref using Op amp, like this:
[image]

When simulate with TINA using model from TI, instead of 20mV at output (Vref port), i see that it is 27.95mV.

My question is:

- Why I can't get 20mV at Vref
- How to improve this circuit to have accurate 20mV (+/- 5%)
- Any recommendation for me (other way) to have 20mV Vref?

---

Update:

The full schematic here:

Current max is 0.4A, Shunt is 10mOhm. AC voltage is 220V 50Hz. R14/R15~ 100 Ohm

3.3VDC is generate from AC/DC Power supply (using LNK306 - I've have prototype)

I don't want to add negative Power supply because of cost and space of board.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What are you using this for? What output impedance do you require? The maximum offset voltage of that op-amp is more than your error budget (+/-1.8mV) but that does not account for  your simulated results. Try reducing R1 to 10K on the simulation .

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: I am using it for a AC current measurement, but don't want to use addition negative power supply.

Comment: @anhvanthe No way around that. But the fact you need 20mV for AC measurement makes me think you have fundamentally chosen the wrong method to do things. Why do you need such a low reference?

Comment: @DKNguyen: i updated full problem in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a shunt resistance of 10mΩ and maximum current of 0.4A rms the full scale input voltage will only be 4mV rms (11mVpp). Op amp input offset voltage could a similar amount so you may have difficulty getting it trimmed out, and the gain is very high so drift could also be a problem. I suggest using a higher value shunt to get more input voltage, eg. 100mΩ for 40mV rms. Then you can reduce gain so offset voltage and drift are less of a problem, and the reference voltage will be high enough to buffer accurately.

If RV1 is fixed at 10k then you don't even need a buffer. Just give the voltage divider a [Thevenin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem) equivalent resistance of 10k and it will do the same job.

For example:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLeNTt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes. thank for your recommend. I will increase Rshunt and Vref. Sometime I overthought and can't figure out simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your op-amp datasheet.

Your op-amp doesn't have enough common mode input or output range for a voltage so close to its negative supply rail. Honestly, I'm surprised you got as close you did.

Rail-to-rail  means close to rail-to-rail. It never actually means rail-to-rail because ideal transistors do not exist.

Currently, you have used GND/0V as your op-amp's negative supply and it has limited ability to input and output near its supply voltages. You need to replace your op-amp's a negative supply with an actual negative supply below 0V so the op-amp can input and output 0V without needing to get so close to its negative power rail.

Comment: I updated the question.
"Rail-to-rail means close to rail-to-rail" : yes. In my case, i think about offset of op-amp make it not exactly 20mV

Comment: @anhvanthe Can you please explain how your circuit is supposed to work? (What's going on at each input and why you mix mix Vref at the inverting input). It looks kind of like a differential amplifier but I'm not sure why you specifically need 20mV.

Comment: Because my input voltage (current) is sin but the op-amp power supply is single, so I need to move it up to above 0. Then, I want to amplify it, but, if Vref is too high, the output will be saturated. I do the math and choose Vref = 20mV, Voltage at I_SENS ~ 2.25-2.65V (just calculated).

Comment: @anhvanthe Safety issues from directly connecting to the high voltage mains without isolation aside...I still don't understand why you need to offset it to 20mV and not mid-supply (1.65V) if you're worried about saturation after amplification. You said it's a sinusoid after all which has equal swing about zero.

Comment: You are right that safety issue. The end application is for sth like curtain controller, the user will not touch the circuit. Can you explain your suggesion, plz. And, any recommend for op amp, ic is welcome.

Comment: i still need your recommendation for op amp better CMR.

Comment: @anhvanthe Suppose your op-amp saturates at 0V and 3V. Suppose your original sinusoid is centered around zero and reaches from -4mV to 4mV. Why on earth would you want to offset it by 20mV so that it doesn't saturate after amplification? Why wouldn't Why wouldn't you offset it by 1.5V before amplification so that after you amplified 375x it it would reach from 0V to 3V. Your 20mV offset doesn't make any sense. If you offset it by 20mV, you could only amplify it by 5x and the positive peak could be no higher than 40mV because that that point the negative peak would saturate the opamp at 0V.

Comment: Thanks. As I explained that I using amplifying plus offset adjust because I don't want to add more negative power supply (-5V or -3.3V), and, with 20mV and 50 gain, our MCU can read easily.

Comment: @anhvanthe That still doesn't address what I am saying since your MCU can still accept all the way up to 3.3V/ 5V. 20mV peak on top of a 20mV offset with 50 gain with is still only 2V. You do not use all your positive headroom nor do you address negative clipping after amplification since your sinusoid dips below its bias point just as much it rises above it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simulating the circuit shown above, the op-amp is being called upon to sink a fair amount of current, so it won't be able to get all the way to 0V. Otherwise it should work in reality, and probably in simulation.

There are values missing from the schematic and voltages are not shown so I have not put a lot of effort into analyzing it, but try putting a 50 or 100 ohm resistor from the op-amp output U4B to ground. That will reduce the gain significantly but it should work typically. The worst-case error is still higher than your error budget due to Vos but typical is 250uV.

Comment: Thanks @Spehro Pefhany. Do you have any recommendation for the op-amp or voltage reference?